# Proving an upper bound on trigonometric polynomial

Tags: analysis, inequality, trigonometric-series

Let $k$ be a natural number. Apparently it is possible to show that there is a choice of
$0<n_1\leq n_2\leq \cdots \leq n_k$ with $n_i$ integers such that as $k\rightarrow \infty,$

$$
\max_{\theta \in (0,2\pi]} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k \sin n_i \theta\right|\leq ck^{2/3}$$

for some constant $c>0,$
but I cannot find a reference.

**Edit:** Regarding the comment, I am happy with even a sequence $(n_i)$ which changes with $k$, to start with.

For background see this MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395776/tight-upper-bounds-on-trigonometric-polynomials)

Comment: Are the integers $n_i$ fixed for all $k$, or they can vary for different $k$? The current phrasing seems a bit ambiguous.